# Limit the data for spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am reading the data from NOSQL database using spark dataframe. Since there is limit to load maximum of 40MB data in databricks, i am looking for a solution to limit the data. I have tried using limit() or take() options but both are giving me an error since they read whole data first and limit later.

While reading itself it is throwing an error, is there anyway we can limit the data before reading entire dataset? We filtered the data and taking only two columns but still this data is huge.

```
ReadData = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri",connectionstring).option("pipeline",pipeline).load().limit(2000)
```

Comment: what is the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16501: &apos;Query exceeded the maximum allowed memory usage of 40 MB

Comment: This is a limitation from databricks and they will solve in next version.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the intension of reading small portion of data. One option could be try to apply a filter, which could be pushed down to the DB and could result in less number of records.

Comment: Thanks you, we are filtering the data and unfortunately we cannot filter based on anytime frame since we do not have these fields for that table. Though we have few standard filter, still we are facing issue. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure, if there is some other way. May be we beed to raise a req in spark community.